# Maintain form Position in asp.net mvc on post back (submit)

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to Maintain form Position in asp.net MVC on post back (submit)
Please help me 
i am doing like this what not get desired result.

```
  $(function () {
                var posName = location.href + "_top";
                $(window).unload(function () {
                    var top = $(document).scrollTop();
                    $.cookie(posName, top);
                });

                var goTop = parseInt($.cookie(posName));
                if (goTop) {
                    $(document).scrollTop(goTop);
                    $.cookie(posName, "");
                }
            });
```

Comment: Does m clear my question please help me?

Comment: Are you trying to scroll the browser to a specific form element?

Comment: no m submitting the form and after submit i have lost my current positions i want my current position back.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scroll to your form, you can use something like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#frm").offset().top});
});
```

You also can do it by [jQuery.scrollTo()](http://flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) plugin which is easier to use and understand:

```
$('body').scrollTo('#frm');
```

Comment: I want my position(where m on the page) back after post back.

Comment: @JatinderSharma - Suppose that you have a magical method named `myScroll()`. Show me a psuedo-code and put this imaginary method where it should be in order that I could help you